# iPhone app consumables - Server vs keychain method

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I had an iPhone app developed by a company, which contains consumables purchases, specifically a currency named as "coins", used for app-specific purchases. In the current version, the team has added the ability for a user to register under a username/email/password. This information is stored on my external server and used as a recovery for the user's purchased coins via signing in using these credentials.

The model looks fine programmatically but is not convenient in terms of usability. Ideally, i would want my users to not have to register at all. I have been reading that it is a possibility to store the user's purchased consumables on the client side, using the internal keychain.

Now this would imply that consumables can only be restored on this single device (i guess unless iCloud is used). But is this allowed by Apple ? Or there should be a method to restore across different devices ?

If the keychain method is allowed, I believe that it would be way better for my app to go with that. I just wanted to make sure that Apple would not have a problem with that. I have been reading that it's allowed, but do not want to have unpleasant surprised after changing the whole client-server model to client-only keychain.

If you have experience with that, could you please let me know what the case is ?

EDIT : Somewhere on SO I read that using Gamecenter's GKPlayer class is also a way to store information on my server and retrieve that automatically in order to identify a user purchase. This would mean that the step of username/email registration is avoided, which is something i really really want to avoid. Is this really a possibility that is allowed by Apple ?

EDIT 2 : I am now thinking that I will keep the client-server model but lose the username/password and use the device id instead. This way i will be able to keep the restoration of coins working on a specific device. Would that be ok you think?